# Update from "Azure media service" to "Media Encoder Standard"

Tags: php, azure, media, azure-media-services, encoder

We have been using **`Azure Media Services`** for converting video, audio and video thumbnails to various formats. Recently, We discovered that `Azure Media Services` is not supported in Europe.

Since Window **`Azure Media Services`** is deprecated for Europe, we can not use it and have to update to `Media Encoder Standard`

> [**The week of December 3, 2012, we will be deprecating and removing
>   version 1.5.3 of Windows Azure Media Encoder.**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f8c87a3d-940f-4189-990f-80bebee4086d/notice-on-upcoming-changes-to-windows-azure-media-encoder?forum=MediaServices)

We already have existing system which uses `Azure Media Services` for converting video, audio and video thumbnails to various formats, size etc.But As suggested by Amazon we should update and use `Media Encoder Standard` instead of using `Azure Media Standard`.

> What are the difference between these two. I need to get clear idea for this to update it to **Media Encoder Service**. If anyone has already done this, please guide me.

Any Help would be much appreciated.

> > > **Note** . Looking for comparison
> >
> > 1. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/advanced-encoding-features-in-azure-media-encoder/
> >
> >    2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-mes-presets-overview

Comment: Any guidance on this is appreciated thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, Azure Media Services is still available in the West Europe and North Europe regions - it is just that the legacy "Windows Azure Media Encoder" component has been deprecated and replaced by "Media Encoder Standard" (MES).

The latter, MES, has almost all of the features of the former - notable exclusion is that MES does not support VC-1/WMA as an output format. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-general-availability-of-media-encoder-standard/ for more details about the differences.

If you can share more details about the Presets that you were using with Windows Azure Media Encoder, we can provide help converting them to the MES schema.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we are using it for transcoding the video, Audio & Thumbnail. If you can provide details about those it would be helpful